# Why should SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON be with XML methods?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

The documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-warnings-transact-sql does not say about XML, the database defaults to OFF, there is a database trigger in which the contractors added this setting saying that for XML it should be ON:

```
create trigger tDDLLog on database
for DDL_DATABASE_LEVEL_EVENTS
as
SET NOCOUNT ON
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON --contractors added this and…
declare @data XML = EVENTDATA()
if (select @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]','varchar(max)')) is not null
insert DDLLog (LoginName,HostName,ObjectName,ObjectType,EventType,EventSQLCommand,EventTime,XMLChange)
values (
 @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/LoginName)[1]','varchar(2000)')
 ,HOST_NAME()
 ,@data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]','varchar(100)')
 ,@data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectType)[1]','varchar(100)')
 ,@data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]','varchar(100)')
 ,@data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand)[1]','varchar(max)')
 ,getdate()
 ,@data
)
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF --… this
go
```

On the Internet I found such a message " *'ANSI_WARNINGS'. Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations.* " But why then the trigger worked with mine updates stored procedures and interfered with the contractor? I can’t recreate the situation... I would like to know what other hidden difficulties are there?

Comment: Ask your contractors. ON is and should be the default setting simply because OFF can cause issues. You can never know when this problem will come up in the future as the code and system evolve. The better question is why you think your system should use the OFF setting.

Comment: We are rather dependent on the contractor and cannot dictate the conditions, but I think the system does have a lot of not ISO code... this is an old development

Answer (score 0):

Information on XML methods database settings requirements can be found here:

[Required query options | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/retrieve-and-query-xml-data?view=sql-server-ver16#query)

Essentially it states the following (Taken from webpage):

When querying xml type columns or variables using xml data type methods, the following options must be set as shown.

**SET Options/Required Values**

```
ANSI_NULLS  ON
ANSI_PADDING    ON
ANSI_WARNINGS   ON
ARITHABORT  ON
CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT  OFF
QUOTED_IDENTIFIER   ON
```

If the options aren't set as shown, queries and modifications on xml data type methods will fail.